# Increase time in date in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

How to increase `10` seconds in JavaScript query in the following date format.

My date is: `2020-04-30 16:51:42`

My expected output is: `2020-04-30 16:51:52`

Comment: @Gerard this answer in output format not proper

Comment: There are many questions about how to format a Date in JavaScript: [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3552461/215552), for instance.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Date.setSeconds() method to set the seconds.

Look at this link: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setSeconds

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code

```
var d = new Date("2020-04-30 16:51:42");
d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds()+10);
console.log(d);
```

Better idea is convert to millis long number and add (10 * 1000)

```
var d = new Date("2020-04-30 16:51:42");
var mil = d.getTime();
mil = mil + (10 * 1000)
console.log(new Date(mil));
```

`1000` millisecond = `1` second

For Safari browser this format will work

```
var d = new Date("2020/04/30 16:51:42");
```

Comment: What does `new Date("2020-04-30 16:51:42")` return in Safari? See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)